# What happened to my question? All I did was forget to put in a tag

Tags: support, asking-questions

I spent about 30 minutes composing a question and then posted it. Unfortunately I forgot to put any tags on it.

Now my question is not showing up (so I can edit the tags), and I am wondering if I lost all of that work. Is my question going to come up in time or what?

If it got saved as a draft, I can't figure out where to find that.

Comment: "If it got saved as a draft, I can't figure out where to find that." Try going back to the Ask Question page and see if it's still there.

Comment: If it happens again, just hit Back after you fail to submit it. You probably don't have the history any more though

Comment: "Try going back to the Ask Question page".  Yes, this worked.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It won't let you submit if you don't add any tags. It will just refresh the page and show you:

[image]

If you closed the tab , thinking that it got submitted, don't worry, head off to "ask a question" and the draft will be there--provided you haven't written any other questions on the same site in the meantime.

The same goes for answers--they get saved as drafts, and can be accessed by going to the answer box on the relevant question page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  This solved my problem.